# How to send all ECS Services Logs to LogStash

Tags: logstash, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to forward all AWS ECS logs to Logstash. Checking some documentation for that I only found ways to have specific Cloudwatch logs groups defined:

```
input {
    cloudwatch_logs {
        log_group => ["/aws/ecs/a","/aws/ecs/b","/aws/ecs/c","/aws/ecs/d","/aws/ecs/e","/aws/ecs/f"]
        start_position => "end"
        access_key_id => "<access_key>"
        secret_access_key => "<secret_access_key>"
        region => "eu-west-2"
        tags => ["cloudwatch_syslog"]
    }
}
```

Is any way to forward all logs inside "/aws/ecs/*"?

Other nice solution possible?

Comment: You could try using log_group_prefix => true. The code will then use describe_log_groups  to find groups that match the prefix. If log_group => [ "" ] then that might match everything.

Comment: It doesn't work adding empty, but if you add some text it use as a prefix. Thanks. @Badger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AWS Firelens for log forwarding works fine.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/logs/forward-logs/aws-firelens-plugin-log-forwarding/